# List attachment to Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a flow created that when a list item is created, the attachment goes to a document library. I cannot seem to figure out how to have select list column data also transfer to the library with the attachment. Currently I can only get the document name and created by. Is there a way to get it to pull other data submitted in the list with the attachment?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question completely.

You can use **Get Item** (not Get Item**s**!!) to get all properties of a list item. Then edit the properties of the file in its new location in the library and pull the properties from the Get Item step.

Comment: You also always have the option of calling any of the REST API endpoints using 'Send HTTP Request to SharePoint" action, if the available SharePoint actions aren't flexible enough for your needs.